# Custom validation message ignored in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create a custom validation rule as folows:

```
$validator
    ->add('slug', 'custom', [
        'rule' => function($value, $context) {
            return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $value);
        },
        'message' => 'Slug cannot contain spaces or special characters'
    ]);
```

The rule works fine, but the message on form is always: `"The provided value is invalid"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to cast to boolean the return value, as `preg_match()` returns `0|1`.

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $value);
```